# Groovy-Eclipse 2.5.2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: picocli.CommandLine$ParameterException

Tags: groovy, groovy-eclipse, picocli

I'm using Eclipse 4.5 with the Groovy-Eclipse 2.9.2/4.5 plugin which I thought was supposed to have the Groovy 2.5 compiler.  However, it didn't have any picocli support so I added the `groovy-cli-picocli-2.5.2-indy.jar` to my classpath and was able to compile.  However #2, when trying to run the script via Eclipse I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: picocli.CommandLine$ParameterException
```

It looks like `groovy-cli-picocli-2.5.2-indy.jar` does not have `CommandLine` class at all.

I would just throw jars at this from the fullblown picocli distribution but I'm under the impression they all have to somehow wrap nicely into Eclipse Groovy library via `groovy.cli.picocli.CliBuilder`.

Is my Groovy 2.5.2 missing this or am I somehow missing the boat on how it's supposed to work because picocli is not working for me in this configuration.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: `groovy-cli-picocli-2.5.2.jar` (and `groovy-cli-picocli-2.5.2-indy.jar`) do not contain the picocli classes.

You need to add the picocli jar to the classpath.

If you use Maven, the groovy-all POM should include all dependencies.

(My original answer mentioned picocli classes that are shaded into the groovy-2.5.x.jar under the `groovyjarjarpicocli` package but these are intended for use internally by Groovy and not meant to be used by applications.)

Comment: I updated my answer. My first answer was misleading. Apologies.

Comment: With groovy 2.4 there was a groovy-all jar. From 2.5 this has been replaced with a groovy-all POM dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.5.2